# Using Rectbivariate over 2 matrices of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using `scipy.interp2d` to interpolate over a bunch of coordinates of points:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

grid_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
grid_y = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
grid_z = np.zeros((grid_size_kc,grid_size_kp))*5

function = RectBivariateSpline(x = grid_x, y = grid_y, z =  grid_z)
```

I would like to interpolate over two matrices of coordinates

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
```

So that it would return the interpolated values at `x=1,y=5`, `x=2, y=6`, `x=3, y=7`, etc. Right now, I am simply looping over all potential values but this slows down my code quite a bit and I am trying to use vectorized operations to make things quicker.

Ideally, this would return an array of size `10x10` with all the interpolated values.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy answer to this, when you call your 'function', juste write

```
function(x, y, grid = False)
```

Hope this will be useful for somebody.